# multiple uid for tagged friend in photos not working

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags

multiple uid for tagged friend in photos not working. below code is worked for single user only.. i passed the three uid in array after i passed them into foreach and that processed variable passed into the facebook graph api..how to tagged those 3 uid in facebook using graph api (`$argstag`). Can anyone help me ... Any help is appericiated.. Thanks in advance

```
$friends_tag_array[]=array('uid'=>'1472898480','x'=>'40','y'=>'40');

                      $friends_tag_array[]=array('uid'=>'100002109469765','x'=>'40','y'=>'40');

                      $friends_tag_array[]=array('uid'=>'561260191','x'=>'40','y'=>'40');

                      //echo '<pre>'; print_r($jsonfrnd); echo '</pre>'; die();
                      for($i=0;$i<count($friends_tag_array);$i++)
                      { 
                      foreach($friends_tag_array as $value)
                      { 
                      //print_r($value); die();

                      $friend = $value['uid'];  
                      //$frndId = $friends_tag_array[$i]['uid'];

                      $argstag = array('to'=>$friend);

                      $argstag['x'] = '40';

                      $argstag['y'] = '40';

                      }
                      } 

                     try 
                        {
                            $res = $facebook->api('/'.$json->id.'/tags', 'POST', $argstag);
                        }   catch (FacebookApiException $e) {

                            Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError($post_process_view->render(POST_PROCESS_TEMPLATES,'post_process-error.phtml'));

                       }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the below code works for me while multiple tagging. hope it helps you as well in debugging your problem

```
$friends_id = array('1472898480','100002109469765','561260191')
 $tags = array();
         foreach ($friends_id as $id)
         {
            $tag = array();
            $tag['tag_uid'] = $id;
            $tag['x'] = rand() % 100;
            $tag['y'] = rand() % 100;
            $tags[] = $tag;
         }
          $argstag = array(
            'tags' => $tags
          );

          $facebook->api("$photoId/tags","POST", $argstag);
```

Comment: how to i get uid from selected user in autocomplete textbox for friend.. any idea

Comment: above code is suddenly stopped working for me don't know why this happened

Comment: I use the same code without any change .. and it does works for me ... make sure You are not trying to tag more than 50 friends at time otherwise it won't work... check out https://apps.facebook.com/my-sketch-roo . draw something, save and then tag friends if u wish .. you can see tagging is working very well...

Comment: i m passed only 3 uid in my code currently it only post the image on users wall but tagged friend not shows....

Comment: try putting `$facebook->api("$photoId/tags","POST", $argstag);` in `try catch` statement and check if it is throwing any exception. those friends may have the setting to not allow tag, in that case they won't be tagged. try to tag yourself ..

Comment: my code is already in try & catch also i tagged my self still only image is posting....